# Razor pages button on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I link a button click to a method on Razor pages, am using ASP.NET Core 6?

I have this bit of code from a razor pages **Test.cshtml**

`<Button>Do some stuff</Button>`

and I want to link it to this method from **Test.cshtml.cs**

`public void SomeStuff()   { //Some C# code   }`

I know how to do it if it was a post form but is there any other way to invoke that method?

Trying to link a button click event from a cshtml razor pagee to a function in a cshtml.cs file

Comment: You are looking for Handler Methods: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: does it have to be a post? no other way?

Comment: @Jay Browsers only speak HTTP. I'm not sure what other way you are thinking it could work, but any web framework is going to make POSTs, GETs, etc. even if it is abstracted to the point where you don't realize it.

Comment: @Crowcoder got it, i was thinking like javascripts <Button onclick=“someFunction()></button>, so that is still a POST or GET, right ?, and thanks for clearing that out

Comment: No, JavaScript events are not http requests though you can certainly make http requests in the event handler which is the only way to interact with the server.

Comment: `OnGetMyHandler()` will work with GET's

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to link a button click event from a cshtml razor pagee to a
> function in a cshtml.cs file

Can you use this way ?

Wrap the [anchor tag element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in the button element and is able to navigate to the specified page  method when the button was clicked.

```
<button ><a asp-page-handler="SomeStuff" class="nav-link text-dark">Do some stuff</a></button>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public  void OnGetSomeStuff() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way ?

```
<Button id="ButtonID">Do some stuff</Button>

<script>
$("#ButtonID").click(function() {
CallAjaxMethod("/Test/SomeStuff/").then(function (result) {
       // Your action after getting the response
    });
});
</script>
```